# How do I unpair iPhone as the microphone of my macbook?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, icloud, microphone

One year ago, while using an external Dell display as my monitor, I consistently kept my MacBook closed to concentrate on a single screen.

However, I encountered an issue: the MacBook's microphone doesn't work when it's closed, prompting me to use an external microphone. I discovered some articles about using an iPhone as a microphone, which worked well.

But after selling my external display and switching back to using only my MacBook, a new problem arose. My MacBook ALWAYS connects to the iPhone as its microphone, regardless of the distance between them (like when the iPhone is in another room, such as the kitchen).

Each time, I have to manually disconnect it on the iPhone, but they automatically reconnect after a few hours.

How can I permanently unpair my iPhone as a microphone from my MacBook?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a setting on the iPhone:

> To prevent your Mac from recognizing your iPhone as a camera or microphone, even when your iPhone is plugged in and mounted, you can turn off Continuity Camera:
>
> 1. On your iPhone, go to Settings > General > AirPlay & Handoff.
> 2. Turn off Continuity Camera.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/102546